# Docpad - Ignoring specific filetypes from copying

Tags: docpad

I've checked the whole config list, but I couldn't find any option to specify filetypes that I don't want to include on generating the project. I think about ignoring '.styl' stylus files from copying into the production directory.

Of course I can delete them manually, but is not a solution.

So how can I prevent specific filetypes from copying to the out dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using something similar to the [`ignoreincludes` plugin](https://github.com/rantecki/docpad-plugin-ignoreincludes). It was made mainly for `.less` and `.styl` files.

This post by Richard goes over making this plugin: http://richard.antecki.id.au/posts/2013/05/ignoring-extensions-docpad.html

He basically goes over the several things he tried in order to achieve this.

Hope this helps. :)